# "hearing him speak" or "hearing him speaking"

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

The sentence:

> Probably, after hearing him **speak** in English, they allowed him to enter in the pub.

So, can I use *speaking* in place of *speak*?

Comment: In this instance, the gerund-participle could be substituted for the infinitive.

Comment: @user55697 You should say "enter the pub," NOT "enter IN the pub."

Comment: When gerund participle could be substituted for infinitive @ pe dant

Comment: When? In the sentence in your question. Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: @user55697 there is no rule; when a gerund may be substituted depends on which verb is being used; when a gerund might be substituted depends on style issues, including the context.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can - either of these work:

> Probably, after hearing him **speak** in English, they allowed him to enter the pub.

or

> Probably, after hearing him **speaking** in English, they allowed him to enter the pub.

(Note that in both cases I dropped the "*in" from the final clause, is it is not correct)

Comment: What's the difference in meaning between the two sentences?

Comment: Good question @userr2684291.  The meaning is almost the same.   In the first one "they" might have "heard him speak" just once and it could be short. The second one implies that the "speaking" is going on for some time, and perhaps "they" just overheard it.